# rails 6 has_many relation on multiple databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I am junior RoR developer.
I have this architecture:

- 2 databases on different hosts
- 1 application with multiple databases setted on database.yml

in my first database I storing `Vacancies` in the second database I storing `Users`

VacancyController

```
def create
    @vacancy = Vacancy.new(vacancy_params)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(database: { writing: :secondary }) do
        @vacancy.save
    end
end
```

As you can see, I am storing using rails 6 activeRecord feature on my secondary database.

Vacancy.rb model has next relation:
    belongs_to :user

User.rb model has next relation:
        has_many :vacancies, dependent: :delete_all

So the first db has no Vacancies table and the second db has no Users table.

I have this error when I try to create `Vacancy`:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'secondary.users' doesn't exist
```

I thinking that this happens because first db has no Vacancies table and the second db has no Users table.
Also i can't create mission tables fore each db.
How I can solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For features Googlers, solution is to define relations like this

vacancy model

```
def user
    ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to( database: { reading: :primary } ) do
        User.where( id: user_id ).first
    end
end
```

I don't know if this is elegant solution, but it works.